# Trying to use foursquare explorer api to search by category

Tags: ios, httprequest, foursquare

I want to make a restaurant near you finder app, and am planning to use the four square api to so. I want to use the explorer api so the user can search "American restaurants near me" instead of searching for a specific restaurant like "Subway near me". But with the explorer I can't search by category. The default http request they give us is this:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=40.7,-74
```

Now I am trying to add a parameter that allows the user to search restuarants by category. So I looked at foursquares categories and found american restaurants and found the key for that category and placed it in as a parameter like the following:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?section=4bf58dd8d48988d14e941735&section=4bf58dd8d48988d10f941735&ll=40.7,-74
```

But when I search like this I get the same results as the default, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=users/self you find the API explorer where you can shape your query url before writing it into your code. but if you change section=Category_ID to categoryId=Category_ID then you should get the results you are looking for. for example: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=40.7,-74&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d14e941735